# How can I get my bluetooth tws/headset battery level in flutter ? (individual buds battery level as well as case battery level)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies, batterylevel, bluetoothheadset

I'm trying to build an app using flutter which gets battery level of currently connected Bluetooth headset or TWS.

Comment: A headset does connect to your phone via bluetooth classic to stream music, not BLE. The battery level might be offered via BLE but that is not always the case.

Comment: So Can I get headset battery level using ble and HOW ?
There are many apps in play store which shows battery percentage of connected bluetooth device (headset)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Harsh but are the using BLE or bluetooth classic? Have you tried using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if the headset offers a standard battery service?

Comment: The tws i used were nothing ear 1, which has a dedicated app that shows battery percentage of both buds as well as case, when I used nRF Connect, it says that it is LE only device type and I can see list off UUIDS.